Setting the max Step Size of a Solver in Dymola (espcial CVOde)
is there a method/way to set the max step size within a Dymola modell?
Espacially when using the CVOde Solver
the CVODE Sundial solver has a functionality
CVodeSetMaxStep
see this link https://sundials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cvode/Usage/index.html#c.CVodeSetMaxStep

Since Dymola 2020x you can influence the solver step size with the following variables:
Advanced.Simulation.StepSizeMax    // maximum step-size
Advanced.Simulation.StepSizeMin    // minimum step-size
Advanced.Simulation.StepSizeStart  // initial step-size

You can set them from the command line or in the variable editor, which is accessed via File > Variables in newer Dymola versions.

Chapter 5.2.12 Simulation settings in the full user manual provides some additional information for those flags.

Thanks...
Don't know why I wasn't able  to find it myself.
